# How to say in Cantonese, "He is very sensitive to criticism"

Tags: cantonese, topolect

What is the right way to say, "He is very sensitive to criticism" in Cantonese?

Comment: this is a different phrasing ... i want to know this specific phrasing as well.

Comment: Your question appears to be off-topic here - you seem to just be asking for a translation.

Comment: ok fair enough, will close the question

Answer (score 1):

oh sorry, you need cantonese. "距对批评好敏感”

Comment: 距 is wrong. The third person pronoun in Cantonese is 佢 (more customary nowadays) or 渠 (the original character).

Comment: You should edit your answer instead of posting a new one.